# Configure HP iLO MTU Setting - Site is behind several firewalls and MTU requires lowering for access

Tags: networking, remote-access, hp-proliant, mtu

Just wondering if anyone knows how to adjust the MTU setting for a HP server iLO NIC?

The site is behind several firewalls and we have had problems with other things that has required us to lower the MTU on desktop PC's to access items at head office, and we can't access iLO from head office so I presume that we need to lower the MTU on the iLO NIC but have NO idea how :)

help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path MTU discovery is broken in some versions of iLO firmware. Upgrading or downgrading to a version where it works should solve your problem. You don't mention which version of iLO is involved however.

[ilo2 (2.15) PMTU discovery broken](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/ilo2-2-15-PMTU-discovery-broken/m-p/5987679)

[iLO 2 Firmware version 2.20 released](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ITRC-Remote-Lights-Out-Mgmt-iLO/iLO-2-Firmware-version-2-20-released/td-p/6067313)

Latest seems to be 2.22 - [HP Integrated Lights-Out 2 (iLO 2)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?cc=us&prodNameId=1135772&prodSeriesId=1146658&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1005)

With working path MTU discovery you won't need to set it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [python-hpilo](http://seveas.github.io/python-hpilo/) to do update your firmware, and as brian's answer says, that should fix it - `hpilo_cli ip.of.ilo.here update_rib_firmware filename=latest` (As per the documentation [here](http://seveas.github.io/python-hpilo/ilo.html)) should update you to the latest firmware.

Comment: Thanks for your help also Mate - seems that Brian got in first but its hard to tell on here...

Comment: Oh, he did get here first